# How to share an sqlite data source between an Activity and FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-activity, listactivity

I used Eclipse to create master detail flow and would now like to use a sqlite data source between the list activity in the master detail flow (of type `FragmentActivity`) and another activity I have created (of type `Activity`).

I did some reading and in order to have only one instance of the sqlite data source, people suggest to make a base activity (of type `Activity`, containing the data source) and then extending it for all the other activities. This way I could grab the resource from the super class... This is all good, but I cannot extend the base activity in the list activity of the master detail flow because it extends `FragmentActivity` and not `Activity`...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would use my own Application class instead of a base activity...

Comment: android noob here... can you elaborate? how do i get reference to my `Application` from both the `Activity` and `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what WarrenFaith was suggesting in his comment is to extend the `Application` class which would then allow you to maintain a global `static` object which can be accessed from any of your app's components.

Example...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static MyObject obj = null;

    public void onCreate() {

        obj = new MyObject();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

You would then access the object from either your `Activity` or your `FragmentActivity` as follows...

```
MyApp.obj.someMethod();
```

Comment: As the Application class will be instantiated only once, you should consider making it a singleton.

Comment: @WarrenFaith : Agreed but I didn't wan't to complicate the issue with the concept of singletons although I did consider mentioning it. My example is just a simple starting point for achieving the desired effect (one I learned when first starting with Android).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, still I'll share a bit of what I've done over here, maybe it will help.

While using fragments I use  getActivity() on the Fragment to pass onto my SQLite DS Objects. This returns the Activity the fragment is associated with.

On the FragmentActivity, I see a method called getParent() which returns the parent Activity depending on how the FragmentActivity is being used.